# How to slide div content left right..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am developing a `wordpress` plugin, where I have to move content in slider from left to right and right to left.
I just tried as:

```
 var effect = 'slide';
   // Set the options for the effect type chosen
   var options = { direction: 'right' };
   // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
   var duration = 700;
jQuery("#letsee").html(data).hide().toggle(effect, options, duration);
```

see the reference [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkiWether/KFmLv/)

So what should I do to make it run. I am appling this for response of ajax.

**Problem:** There is no effect like jsfiddle example, and content is just coming without any effect.
So how can I make the slide left to right, right to left...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Checked your Fiddle.Its seems like working fine.

Comment: Have you included the correct scripts for jQueryUI with the required effects?

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working fine, also i found this another fiddle related to yours, check if that solves what youre trying to achieve.. http://jsfiddle.net/ben1729/CtNsE/2/

Comment: Works fine in FF and Chrome, problem with IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you missed including [jQuery UI library](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js).

```
jQuery UI 1.11.0
```

Hope this will help !

Comment: Which version of jQuery and jQuery UI you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

in your code  data variable is undefined

```
data = "only for testing";
    $('#myDiv').html(data).hide().toggle(effect, options, duration);
```

fiddle : [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/KFmLv/561/)

Comment: is response type json  or simple html

Comment: may be data variable is empty try to console it

Comment: but in fiddle it ran with effect